# Where the bug of this code

Tags: php, readfile, strpos

I have a simple code that doesn't work correctly, I have a file like this:

```
David
Jordan
Steve
```

& in a simple PHP code:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("file.txt");

while (!$file->eof()) {

    $array[]=$file->fgets();
}
$string = 'Hi , I\'M David';

if(strposa($string, $array)){
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}

function strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset=0) {
if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
foreach($needle as $query) {
    if(strpos($haystack, $query, $offset) !== false) return true; // stop on first true result
}
return false;
}
```

but this code doesn't work correctly , 
if

```
$string = 'Hi , I\'M David';
```

It's Return false but when $string change to:

```
$string = 'Hi , I\'M Steve';
```

It return True!

Answer (score 1):

finally, I find three ways to fix this .
way 1 => use rtrim function:

```
$array[]=rtrim($file->fgets());
```

way 2 => use str_replace function :

```
$array=str_replace("\r\n","",$array);
```

or

```
   $array[]=str_replace("\r\n","",$file->fgets());
```

way 3 => use file function :

```
$array = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Answer (score 0):

The output from $file->fgets() function will contain newline character \n at the end. That's why strpos() function is returning false.

You have to clear the newline character from fgets() function by using trim() function.